# Why is my iframe blocked by cross origin even it is not

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a `<iframe>` inside a `<div>`. My outer url is `http://localhost:9090` and the src in iframe is `http://localhost:9090/Server/v1`. In my outer context I have below code to access iframe dom:

```
const f1 = window.frames[iframeName];
const iFrameHead = f1.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
```

and I get an exception on the second line:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:9090" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

The reason I want to access ifame dom is that I need to insert a script into that iframe. The src in iframe has the same protocol, hostname and port number. What I don't understand is the iframe is on the same origin as the parent context. Why does it complain about the cross origin?

After some debugging, I found there is because the `iframe` was redirected to a different domain than its `src`. I wonder whether there is a workaround to insert a script into this iframe?

Comment: different port, try to make a ssh tunnel. https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example

Comment: both use 9090 as the port number. Why do you say it is a different port?

Comment: just a shot in the air, need more info whats going on, thats tipically that error msg

Comment: which error msg said about different port?

Comment: are you in https?

Comment: Has the child frame been navigated since its `src` was set?

Comment: No it is not navigated. I can see it from the chrome develop tool that it is same. Also the error message says the same domain url

Comment: @duskwuff after some debug and I found the iframe did redirect to a different domain. Do you know whether there is a solution to solve this issue?